# store data in nsdictionary from uitableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsdictionary

I have a custom editable `UITableview`, and my question is how to store it's value in `NSDictionary` when I tapped on submit button. My table is like a simple registration form.

Comment: And what you have coded for that

Comment: I am using custom uitablviewcell in which I have two text fields(i.e. age and gender) So, My question is how to store these 2 text fields in nsdictionary through tag?

Comment: [yourdict setObject:textfield.text forKey:propertyName]; was that so difficult....

Comment: If I understand you, you want to get data from a UItableViewCell back into the viewController with the tableView and dictionary. There are two main ways of doing this, you can create a delegate for the cell or create a block on the cell. So once the textfilds are finished being edited call the delegate/block with the new data. Then have the vc save it.

Comment: No because i am using cell.textlabel.text.  and i put data on dictionary when  button clicked(i.e. Submit button).

Comment: yes i created this.     cell.txtField.delegate = self;
    cell.txtField.tag = indexPath.row;
in cellforrow.

Comment: Maybe what you can do is when you press the button you get the `tableView.visibleCells` and loop through them. Asking each cell for its value stored at cell.txtField.text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comment:

If I understand you, you want to get data from a UItableViewCell back into the viewController with the tableView and dictionary.

There are two main ways of doing this, you can create a delegate for the cell or create a block on the cell. So once the textfilds are finished being edited call the delegate/block with the new data. Then have the vc save it

Using a block:

MyTableViewCell.h

```
@interface MyTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^nameChangedBlock)(NSString *name);

@end
```

MyTableViewCell.m

In something like textfield didFinishEditing:

```
 - (void)textFieldDidFinishEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

   if (textField == self.nameTextfield) {

         self.nameChangedBlock(textField.text)

   } 
}
```

In the ViewController with the TableView, in the datasource method cellforRow

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 // Do your standard stuff create the cell and set data;
 // dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: blah blah

   cell.nameChangedBlock = ^{
        // Alex j thank you 
        [yourNSMutableDictionary setObject:yourobject forKey:yourkey];
   };

    return cell
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have reference to your text fields, just do:

```
[yourNSMutableDictionary setObject:yourobject forKey:yourkey];
```

edit* if you want to fetch info from your uitableview click, check out this link [Use UITableViewCell as Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13330720/use-uitableviewcell-as-button)

Comment: ya I know that but how to store data in nsdictionary through button click from table?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing all information on tap of SUBMIT button, I suggest to store it in,  `- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField` which is delegate method of `UITextField`.

If you're showing a clear button (cross icon) in `UITextField`, then you've to clear particular row from `NSDictionary` when user tap on clear button. For that you've to add, `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField` too.

If you're using `UITextView` then also include appropriate delegate for the same.

The reason behind these are,

- You've user information in real time, means you've few fields in your form, First Name, Last Name, Address, DOB etc. When user in First Name field, and when focus (tap to change) for Last Name (or any other field), the `textFieldDidEndEditing` will get call, and you can save First Name into dictionary.
- At the same time, if you're showing a clear button, when user tap on it when he's in First Name field then `textFieldShouldClear` will get call, the first name will be remove from the dictionary right away.
- If you're preparing a big registration form (or any other form). Say for example taking 20 values from the user, if you're not using this approach, the user information will remain visible in form. Because at any time you can fetch and show particular value from dictionary.

---

Example,

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    NSString *getKey = [self keyForTag:textField.tag];
    if(textField.text.length != 0) {
    [dictionary setValue:textField.text forKey:getKey]; }
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField {
   NSString *getKey = [self keyForTag:textField.tag];
   if([dictionary valueForKey:getKey]) {
   [dictionary removeValueForKey:getKey];}
}

- (NSString *)keyForTag:(NSInteger)tag {
    if(tag == 1) {
       return @"kFirstName";
    }
    else if(tag == 2) {
       return @"kLastName";
    }
    ...
}

- (NSString *)showValueForTag:(NSInteger)tag {
    return [dictionary valueForKey:[self keyForTag:tag]];
}
```